# Launching Spyder from Anaconda prompt

Tags: python, command-line, anaconda, conda, spyder

I just installed a fresh version of Anaconda (never installed before). I created a project called snowflakes and activated it from the command line.

Following along with the tutorial "[Getting started with Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/getting-started/#:~:text=At%20the%20Anaconda%20Prompt%20(terminal,jupyter%2Dnotebook%20and%20press%20Enter.)", it say's that when in a environment you can launch the Spyder IDE (came with Anaconda) by typins `spyder`. However when I try to do this I get:

[image]

Did I miss anything during setup? If so how would I fix this? I have no idea where spyder is installed in case I need to add it to my path variables in Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anaconda will help you see the different environments you have configured, their applications and their packages.

Take the following example:

[image: Anaconda Environment with applications]

In this case, the working environment is kdb and it has the following applications installed: `CMD.exe Prompt`, `Jupyter Notebook` and `VS Code`.

If you have a variety of environments and you want to launch the Spyder for a specific one, from Anaconda's Prompt, then, assuming that you are using Windows, do a search in the Start Menu for Anaconda Prompt and select the prompt for your specific environment that should have Spyder installed.

In the example above, as Spyder was not installed, I had to install it.

Then, once installed, let's open Anaconda's Prompt for that specific environment:

[image: Open Anaconda Prompt for a specific environment]

Once there, you can open Spyder by simply running

```
spyder
```

Note that if Spyder is already running, and if you want to open a new
instance, please pass to it the --new-instance option.

Comment: I tried launching from anaconda prompt and got `'spyder' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` But if I go to the Windows 4 square and type spyder it opens

Answer (score 6):

Spyder is not installed in snowflakes environment yet.

First do 'pip install spyder'.

After that type in spyder.

You will be good to go...

Comment: you should try to use `conda install {library}` whenever possible instead of `pip install {library}` to avoid dependency problems

Comment: DaveR is correct.  Spyder developers have advised never mix conda with pip! So install spyder using conda install spyder.